# Chapter, section, etc. numbers on left margin, aligned left

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, memoir

In the memoir class, the "hangnum" chapterstyle puts the section numbers on the left margin, aligned right. How do I change it so that it is aligned left?

Here's an MWE with the original definition of the "hangnum" chapterstyle copied from the manual:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[usehighlevels]{alnumsec}
\alnumsectionlevels{1}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}
\alnumsecstyle{aaaa}
\surroundarabic[{.}][]{}{}
\otherseparators{1}
\alnumsecstyle{aaaa}

\makechapterstyle{myhangnum}{%
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
\settowidth{\chapindent}{\chapnumfont 999}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
\noindent\llap{\makebox[\chapindent][l]{%
\chapnumfont \thechapter}}}
\renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
}

\chapterstyle{myhangnum}
\hangsecnum

\begin{document}

\section{All these section numbers}
\subsection{should be aligned on the left}
\subsection{so that all the first digits}
\subsubsection{which is 1 in this case}
\paragraph{are underneath each other}\

Moreover, is it possible to decrease the space between 
the numbers and the titles? I rarely have paragraphs, 
but I have a lot of subsubsections.

\end{document}
```

I tried adding \hfill inside the makebox, altering the makebox parameters, but both to no avail:

```
\noindent\llap{\makebox[3cm][l]{%
\chapnumfont \thechapter \hfill}}}
```

I also tried altering the macro \chapternamenum (manual: is defined to be a space, is called between printing the chapter name and the number), but even if I enter a string in there, it does not shop up in the finished document.

Comment: I believe (I am no `memoir` expert, however) that `myhangnum` etc. is the wrong drill here. I think, it's rather `\hangnumsec` which has to be changed

Comment: Try putting `\fbox{...}` around the boxes. This isn't to solve the problem - it will help you to see what is going on. At least, it often helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erh, one can just do this via

```
\setsecnumformat{\llap{%
    \makebox[\chapindent][l]{%
      \csname the#1\endcsname\hfill%
    }%
  }}
```

instead of issuing `\hangsecnum`, which by default is the same as

```
\setsecnumformat{\llap{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}}}
```

---

@Ruben

Does this still fail at your end? I should be using the same `memoir` version, but is using `TeLive 2015`

```
\documentclass{memoir} 

\hangsecnum 
\setsecnumformat{\llap{\makebox[\chapindent][l]{\csname
      the#1\endcsname\hfill}}}

\chapterstyle{hangnum} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{All these section numbers}
\subsection{should be aligned on the left}
\subsection{so that all the first digits}
\subsubsection{which is 1 in this case}

\end{document}
```

Comment: and you can control the space between section numbers and section title through changing the first parameter of \makebox (\chapindent in your example), nice! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possibility, though it is very dirtily hacked:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[usehighlevels]{alnumsec}
  \alnumsectionlevels{1}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}
  \alnumsecstyle{aaaa}
  \surroundarabic[{.}][]{}{}
  \otherseparators{1}
  \alnumsecstyle{aaaa}
\usepackage{marginnote}
  \reversemarginpar
\usepackage{xpatch}

\chapterstyle{hangnum}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\M@sect{\protected@edef}{\protected\def}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\@mn@@@marginnote{\@tempswatrue}{\@tempswafalse}{}{}
\marginparwidth 45\p@
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{%
  \raisebox{5\p@}{\marginnote{\raggedright\chapnumfont\thechapter}}
}
\def\@seccntformat#1{\marginnote{\raggedright\csname the#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{All these section numbers}
\subsection{should be aligned on the left}
\subsection{so that all the first digits}
\subsubsection{which is 1 in this case}
\paragraph{are underneath each other}
\end{document}
```

[image: output_crop]